# Como prevenir uma imagem de carregar no mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou tentando prevenir que certas imagens sejam carregadas no mobile, todas estão com **display:none** porém sei que elas serão carregadas por padrão, alguém sabe alguma alternativa que **não** seja utilizando o **background-image**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passando src por javascript caso o tamanho da tela seja maior do que a tela do mobile (estipulada em 480px). Ou se iniciar a página redimensionada em uma largura menor que 480, também não carregará a imagem.

```html
<script>
window.onload = function()
{

 if( window.innerWidth > 480)
 {
  document.getElementById("minhaimagem").src="https://graph.facebook.com/1299814340/picture?type=large";
  document.getElementById("minhaimagem").style.display="block";
 }
}
</script>

<img id="minhaimagem" style="display:none" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando media query do CSS3 só carrega se redimensionar a página, então é o que você procura.

Exemplo - Vai carregar div rosa com a visualização menor ao clicar no botão Executar, e caso você esteja vendo com resolução maior do que 1200 e clique no link "Página toda", vai aparecer sua foto (só fará a requisição da imagem no momento que visualizar em tela cheia). Testado com o Firebug e **não** pré-carrega a imagem em memória.

```html
<style>

.minhaimagem 
{

 background-color:#f00;  
 
 height:200px;
 width:200px;
 
 border: 1px solid #000;

}


/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
 
  .minhaimagem 
  {
   background-color:#f0f;  
   background-image: none);
  } 

    }

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
 
  .minhaimagem 
  {
   background-color:#f0f;  
   background-image: none);
  }  

    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

    }

    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
 
  .minhaimagem 
  {
   background-color:#f0f;  
   background-image: url("https://graph.facebook.com/1299814340/picture?type=large");
  } 

    }


</style>

<div class="minhaimagem">...</div>
```

Comment: tu chegou a ver na pergunta que eu não posso utilizar o background-image?

Comment: Vi, mas essa imagem não é carregada por padrão, achei que serviria. Vou modificar a resposta pra ficar uma coisa diferente.

Comment: Adicionei outra resposta usando javascript passando src pra imagem. Se o tamanho da tela for maior que 480, mostra a imagem.